# How do I change the context path of my Enterprise Project

Tags: netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish

So my enterprise project name `TestProject`, which contain `TestProject-ejb` and `TestProject-war`, so when I run the project the url is like this `locahost:8080/TestProject-war`. How can I change this url to `localhost:8080/testproject`. I use netbean 6.9, I try to right click on `TestProject-war` folder in netbean, and specify the context-path there under `Run`, but it still load `locahost:8080/TestProject-war`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to check that the context-root element for the web module in the application.xml file that's in the META-INF directory of your EAR has been correctly changed.

An example would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
    id="Application_ID" version="6">

    <display-name>TestProject</display-name>

    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>TestProjectWeb.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>testproject</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>

    <module>
        <ejb>TestProjectEJB.jar</ejb>
    </module>

</application>
```

In this example the web module should be available under /testproject of the server you deploy to, so in your case `http://localhost:8080/testproject`.

*(In case you would like to deploy to the root of your server, you can leave the context-root element empty: `<context-root></context-root>`.)*

If you indeed see that your action in Netbeans has correctly changed this file, it may be a deployment problem like BalusC indicated. Check the location the EAR is deployed to and manually inspect whether the deployed version also has the correct value.

Comment: In my META_INF, I only see MINIFEST.MF file, do I just add application.xml there?

Comment: It should have been there already. Double check you are looking in the correct META_INF dir. A typical EAR has many. Do a global search for "application.xml" to be sure. Otherwise go ahead and add one.

Comment: If you had a maven project, don't forget that the version number is automatically added to the modules during deployment. So you would need to specify `TestProjectEJB-1.0.jar` (or whatever your version number is).

Comment: @Arjan What is the equivalent of _<display-name>_ in glassfish 4? I can't seem to find it [here](http://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-deployment-guide.pdf)

Comment: See below.  Netbeans does not create application.xml by default, but it will create it if you tell it to.

Comment: Netbeans has not created Meta_INF folder or application.xml file in my maven web application. How can I add it? If that is NOT available, how can I change the context root? Changing in the properties window does not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

As Harry pointed out the default project template doesn't create an `application.xml` file, so you have to create it by hand at `$ENTERPRISE_APP_PATH/src/conf` (tested with NB 6.9.1)

Comment: The OP stated they are using Netbeans, which means you do not need to create application.xml by hand.  You do need to explicitly tell Netbeans to create it.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this question in the course of figuring out the same thing.  Since the OP was asking about doing this in Netbeans, let me add to previous answers by describing specifically how to do this using the Netbeans IDE.

With Netbeans 8 (and possibly also with earlier versions) you can tell the IDE to create the application.xml file for you, as follows.  Right-click the enterprise application project (in the OP's example this would be "TestProject"), select "New" then "Standard Deployment Descriptor...".  This will create an "application.xml" file and put it in the appropriate place in your Netbeans project.  Then you can easily edit this file to set the context-root element to be whatever you want.