# Catching get request in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

Let's say I have a HTML page and I am running back-end on java and I want to make simple ajax request call.

e.g

```
fetch('localhost:8080/testResponse)
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
```

and on my java server I have

```
@Path('testResponse')
public class NewClass {
    private String name = "MyName";
    private String age = "MyAge";
    @GET
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    @GET
    public String getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

So basically there is get request to /testResponse , and Path annotation indicates what class should catch it but how do I choose what method will get invoked and returns data? Whats the logic behind it? I cannot find anything about it.

/////////////////////////////////

So. I have created new web project in netbeans. It generated html file , i added just basic ajax call to server.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <script>
            fetch('/ajax_test/testResponse/name').then(function(x){
                alert(JSON.stringify(x));
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i run it it shows on localhost:8080/ajax_test

I created a file by comments here e.g

```
@Path("/ajax_test")
public class testik {
    private String name = "MyName";
     private String age = "MyAge";
    @GET
    @Path("/name")
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/age")
    public String getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

Yet its still `404`  did i miss something? Thank you again for help

Comment: What happens when you test it? What do you think should happen in that case?

Comment: I am just not used to having methods for this. I am used to catching get request and returning it using route. Now i have two methods that returns different value and are on the same route.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: you should learn about when we use @Path on top of the methods and why?check out this link:
https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-pathparam-example/

Answer (score 1):

SImply use the @Path to further delineate the endpoint. 
So if you want 'URL Prefix/testResponse/name' and 'URL Prefix/testResponse/age' then do the following:

```
@Path("/testResponse")
public class NewClass {
    private String name = "MyName";
     private String age = "MyAge";
    @GET
    @Path("/name")
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/age")
    public String getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The **first matching** method for your resource `/testResponse` and its annotations will be called, in your case `getName()`. You can add additional annotations, to specialize your methods:

- `@Consumes`: Defines the MIME media types for your request, like `application/json`
- `@Produces`: What MIME media type the data you return has. This attribute corresponds to the `Accept` header you have sent.
- `@Path`: Further sub path to your resource.

In your case, `getName()` will always be called, because it is the first in line and there are no other annotations that differentiate both methods further. Also, since you are using REST resources, each resource must have a unique path, so you could define subresources for `name` and `age` like this:

```
@Path('testResponse')
public class NewClass {
    private String name = "MyName";
    private String age = "MyAge";

    @GET
    @Path("/name")
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/age")
    public String getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

Your resources are then available at `/testResponse/name` and `/testResponse/age`.

Look at the following example. Here, both methods share the same path, namely `/testResponse`, however the actual method to be called is selected by the `Content-Type` header you have sent in your Ajax request. If you set `Content-Type: application/json`, `getJsonName()` is called and analogously for XML and `getXmlName()`.

```
@Path('testResponse')
public class NewClass {
    private String name = "MyName";
    private String age = "MyAge";

    @GET
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public String getJsonName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    @GET
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public String getXmlName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

You can combine this with the other annotations mentioned above. The method to be called is always the first that matches your resource path and request header attributes with the provided annotations.

Comment: I think you miss the project or servlet display name in your path, try `localhost:8080/DISPLAY_NAME_GOES_HERE/ajax_test`. You can find the display name in the *Application deployment descriptor* file `web.xml` in the WEB-INF directory.

Comment: i cannot find anything in that  file that would help

Comment: Sorry, I confused that. To clarify, your path always looks like this: `http://host:port/context-root[/url-pattern]`. It is the **context-root** that you do not know. Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758787/how-do-i-change-the-context-path-of-my-enterprise-project) to find or change it. I hope it helps.

Comment: hm my web.xml file looks completely different.. i will be creating new Question not to be offtopic

Comment: Did you look for `<context-root>...</context-root>` in `application.xml` or `glassfish-web.xml` like mentioned in the linked posts?

Comment: Its not even there , that is the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131295/discussion-between-thatguy-and-johnyb).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly then you want to invoke one of the `GET` methods when you hit `testResponse`. You are allowed to annotate your methods with `@Path` like this:

```
@Path("/")
public class NewClass {
    private String name = "MyName";
    private String age = "MyAge";

    @GET
    @Path("/testSomething")
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/testResponse")
    public String getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Johnyb Why do you say **'/ajax_test/testResponse/name'** in your `fetch()` function? Shouldn't it be just **'/ajax_test/name'**?